# Do deeper residual networks perform better or worse?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, object-detection, residual-networks

If you have an $18$ layer residual network versus and a $32$ layer residual network, why would the former do better at object detection than the latter, if you have both models are training using the same training data?

Answer (score 1):

Just by having more parameters, the deeper model has a **higher capacity** than the smaller one. This means that theoretically it can learn to extract more complex features from the data. Additionally, more layers means that the model can extract even **higher-level features** from the data.
So, generally speaking, deeper models will most of the times **outperform** shallow ones for more difficult tasks.

The downside is that if you have a small amount of data, a high-capacity model has the ability of memorizing the training set, which would lead to **overfitting**. 
Besides performance, deeper models require better hardware and larger training times. So, there are plenty of reasons for one to prefer a more shallow model to a deeper one.